# ¿Automatizar XQuery y HTML?

Tags: html, xml, xquery

estoy peleandome con XQuery para entender su funcionamiento y como podría incluirlo en una web en la que tengo que mostrar cierta información a partir de un fichero XML.

El caso es que usando BaseX genero el "HTML" que luego debería incrustar en la web, pero mi preguntas es si es posible "embeber" el código de XQuery en un fichero HTML (u otro tipo) y que de esa manera, al cargar la página HTML en cuestión se ejecuten ciertas Querys y muestren la info recuperada del XML.